# undefined method `image' for #<Post:0x007f6018a697b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get this error in my porject :

> undefined method `image' for #

```
this is my code : 
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :image
  = f.input :caption
  = f.button :submit
```

this is my model post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        validates :image, presence: true

        has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "640x" }
        validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
end
```

this is my controller post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please add the `schema.rb` part related to posts?

Comment: `class Post < ApplicationRecord; class Post < ActiveRecord::Base` -- What's going on here??!!! That looks definitely wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base`

Newly generated applications have `app/models/application_record.rb`
present by default. Newly generated models have to inherit from `ApplicationRecord`, but only if it's present.

So remove this class `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base` you don't need if you use `rails >= 5` or if you need this then remove the first one.

See this for reference [`Creating Active Record Models`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#creating-active-record-models)

> undefined method `image'

for the `image` attribute not finding to your model, make sure you added that attribute, if you have not that then write a command like this

```
rails g migration AddImageToPosts image:string
```

then run `rake db:migrate`